# Multiply out block matrices in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

```py
n = Symbol('n', integer=True)
f = Symbol('f', integer=True)
A = MatrixSymbol('A', f, n)
B = MatrixSymbol('B', f, f)
C = MatrixSymbol('C', n, f)
D = MatrixSymbol('D', f, f)
expr = (BlockMatrix([[A, B]]) @ BlockMatrix([[C], [D]]))
```

I can't seem to figure out what function to use to simplify `expr` into `A@C+B@D`.

I tried using `block_collapse`, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `block_collapse`:

```
In [8]: expr
Out[8]: 
       ⎡C⎤
[A  B]⋅⎢ ⎥
       ⎣D⎦

In [9]: block_collapse(expr)
Out[9]: A⋅C + B⋅D
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#block-matrices